# Puppet agent not starting?

Tags: networking, unix, puppet, vagrant

I've attached the full output with debug to see if anyone can make sense of what is going wrong. I've tried removing /etc/puppet/ssl/ and the two nodes (agent and master) are able to ping each other by IP and hostname. Using vagrant. Running # puppet cert list comes up with nothing on the master, and I ran a tcpdump on the agent when trying to run the agent, network traffic IS at least being generated targeting the master, not sure what is the problem. Help would be appreciated ^^.

```
[root@vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki vagrant]# puppet agent --test --debug --server=vagrant-puppet-master.pv.com
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"1755", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'vardir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet"}'
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dsimport does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file rolemod does not exist
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'publickeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rundir': 'File[/var/run/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"755", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/run/puppet"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"750", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'plugindest': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/lib"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statefile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"660", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientbucketdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'localcacert': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"644", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunfile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"644", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml"}'
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'logdir': 'File[/var/log/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :group=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"750", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/log/puppet"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'certdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'graphdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'requestdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientyamldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostprivkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"600", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunreport': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"640", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'confdir': 'File[/etc/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :path=>"/etc/puppet"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'ssldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"771", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatekeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"750", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'client_datadir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_data"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostpubkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"644", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem"}'
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: Finishing transaction 70281662410760
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"1755", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'vardir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'publickeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rundir': 'File[/var/run/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"755", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/run/puppet"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"750", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'plugindest': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/lib"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'localcacert': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"644", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'logdir': 'File[/var/log/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :group=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"750", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/log/puppet"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'certdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'requestdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostprivkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"600", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'confdir': 'File[/etc/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :path=>"/etc/puppet"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'ssldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"771", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatekeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"750", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys"}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostpubkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :owner=>"puppet", :mode=>"644", :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem"}'
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: Finishing transaction 70281661077540
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Using cached certificate_request for vagrant-puppet-c664-wiki.pv.com
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled
```

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: Why was this titled "aspiring programmer/sysadmin" and not "puppet agent not starting" by the OP? I'd guess that's part of it.

Comment: This question needs some work in order to meet our quality standards - For starters, please change your title to be relevant to your problem. Next, simply dumping your debug output here and asking us to do all the work is *unacceptable*: We are a site [for professionals](http://serverfault.com/faq) and we expect you to do some legwork yourself ([This meta question has some guidance](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608), but you can start by Googling your error message (`no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled`) and ensuring you've ruled out common problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed `/etc/puppet/ssl`, but (at least on the client) that's not the location being used for the SSL certificate storage.

You might have removed the certificate request from the master, but the client will never send a new certificate request to the master since it thinks it's still just waiting for approval.

Delete the `/var/lib/puppet/ssl/` directory on the client.  Also run `puppet config print ssldir` on the master and verify that it's what you're expecting, as well as `puppet cert list --all` to verify that there isn't already a cert with that client's name.  And make sure if you do delete the SSL directory on the master, that you restart the master service afterward.